# Generating First Set from the grammar

Tags: algorithm, ll-grammar

**[Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser#Constructing_an_LL.281.29_parsing_table) for Finding first set:**

```
Given a grammar with the rules A1 → w1, ..., An → wn, we can compute the Fi(wi) and Fi(Ai) for every rule as follows:

    initialize every Fi(Ai) with the empty set
    set Fi(wi) to Fi(wi) for every rule Ai → wi, where Fi is defined as follows:
        Fi(a w' ) = { a } for every terminal a
        Fi(A w' ) = Fi(A) for every nonterminal A with ε not in Fi(A)
        Fi(A w' ) = Fi(A) \ { ε } ∪ Fi(w' ) for every nonterminal A with ε in Fi(A)
        Fi(ε) = { ε }
    add Fi(wi) to Fi(Ai) for every rule Ai → wi
    do steps 2 and 3 until all Fi sets stay the same.
```

**Grammar:**

```
A -> B C c
A -> g D B
B -> EPSILON | b C D E
C -> D a B | c a
D -> EPSILON | d D
E -> g A f | c
```

**This [website](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/predict-first-follow-set) generates the first set as follows:**

```
Non-Terminal Symbol     First Set

A                        g, ε, b, a, c, d
B                        ε, b
C                        a, c, ε, d
D                        ε, d
E                        g, c
```

But the algorithm says `Fi(A w' ) = Fi(A) for every nonterminal A with ε not in Fi(A)` so the First(A) according to this algorithm should not contain `ε`. `First(A) = {g, b, a, c, d}`.

**Q: First(A) for the above grammar is = `First(B) -  ε U First(C) U {g}` ?**

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uSlP91jmTM) also follows the above algorithm and do not choose  ε.

Comment: Your list of non-terminal symbols contains terminal symbols (`c`, `g`, etc.).

Comment: @Rhymoid: That is generated by the website whose link is given above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
First(B) = {ε, b}
First(D) = {ε, d}
First(E) = {g, c}
First(C) = {c, d, a}
First(A) = {b, g, c, d, a}
```

Example:

```
X -> Y a | b
Y -> c | ε

First(X) = {c, a, b}
First(Y) = {c, ε}
```

First(X) doesn't have ε because if you replace Y by ε, then  First(Y a) is equal to First(ε a) = {a}

First set implementation on my github.

**Edit**: Updated link
https://github.com/amirbawab/EasyCC-CPP/blob/master/src/syntax/grammar/Grammar.cpp#L229
Computing the first and follow sets are both available on the new link above.

Comment: The grammar is correct, and the first set for all the non-terminals is above .. also check the example to understand how to calculate it

Comment: I understood your explanation. It follows the algorithm and why it not use ε  . But the website generated `First(A) =  g, ε, b, a, c, d` which is wrong right?

Comment: Epsilon is not part of the set

Comment: Please check the algorithm in this book page 189. `http://cs.uccs.edu/~gsc/pub/phd/ftorres/doc/Compiler.pdf`. This algorithm adds epsilon to the first set.

Comment: Yes add epsilon to F(x) if the production x > epsilon exists so it's correct. Check tge Y in my example